# How to calculate probability with percentage

Tags: probability

A factory produces a large output of bulbs everyday. If a sample of 30 bulbs is taken at the end of the day, what is the probability that At least 3 bulbs are faulty if 5% of the day's production are faulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculation is a little tedious, but manageable.  The probability that a given bulb is good is $p=.95$. The probability that all thirty bulbs are good is $p_0=p^{30}$.  The probability that exactly one bulb is bad is $p_1=30p^{29}(1-p)$.  The probability that exactly two are bad is $p_2=\binom{30}{2}p^{28}(1-p)^2$. The probablity that three or more are bad  is $1-p_0-p_1-p_2$.